# How to create a file based on the blocks

Tags: linux, filesystems, c, data-recovery, block-device

Recently I'm using nvme-cli to write the data to the block devices, the nvme write and read will allow the user to write to specific blocks. Unfortunately, they don't offer a write or read interface for file-level since maybe the user can just mount the block device.

After I write the file to the specific block with a start number and cost of the block, I can read it back use nvme-cli, sure it do have some extra junk at the end of the file. But how to make the blocks show in the file system? Is there any way I can do to arrange those blocks to a file that can be observed by VFS when I mount the block device? Are there any functions or interfaces that OS fs offered?

I'm using ext4 format for my empty block device. PLease help me...crying.

**Except dd, I can use dd to get the data back to file. but is there any sophisticated way?**

**I have to do this way, because looks like nvme doesn't have a eaiser interface for fs level write or read, to revision the fs is way much harder in my opinio**

Comment: When you write a block device directly, using `dd` or any other command, and want the result to appear in a file, you need to allocate and update directory entries, inodes, file blocks and other data structures on the disk. This would require intimate knowledge of the structures of the particular filesystem on the device. The fact that you ask this question shows that you don't have that knowledge. `nvme-cli`, which I don't know, doesn't seem to have knowledge of filesystems built in either.

Comment: yes. I know basically the call stream from VFS to the exact block dev driver. But I hope there is a way to do it easier, and plus the file system is quite mass to interact with. I have a look at the ext4 source code of the function calling stream, but I'm not sure how to implement it, I do found the function related to block allocation -> ext4_ext_map_blocks(). But I'm not sure it requires me to rewrite a read-write procedure. I need some guidance.